# Get a CompilationUnit from IBinding

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I want to find a declaring node for a `MethodInvocation`:

```
MethodInvocation methodNode = ...;
IMethodBinding b = methodNode.resolveMethodBinding();
IMethodBinding[] declaredMethods = b.getDeclaringClass().getDeclaredMethods();
for (IMethodBinding method : declaredMethods) {
    if (astRoot.findDeclaringNode(method).getStructuralProperty(MethodDeclaration.NAME_PROPERTY).equals(name))
        //...
}
```

This doesn't work in my case, because the method is declared in another compilation unit and `astRoot.findDeclaringNode(...)` returns `null`.
How to get the right `CompilationUnit` from `IBinding`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that `SharedASTProvider#getAST` and `ASTParser#setSource` can work with `ITypeRoot` which is implemented by both `IClassFile` and `ICompilationUnit`. To obtain a `CompilationUnit` from a binding the following snippet can be used:

```
IJavaElement je = b.getJavaElement();
while (je != null && !(je instanceof ITypeRoot)) {
    je = je.getParent();
}
if (je != null) {
    ITypeRoot = (ITypeRoot)je;
    //...
}
```

Learning about `ITypeRoot` helped me to find even better solution which doesn't involve AST and seems to work if source isn't available for a certain class file.

```
for (IMethod method : type.findPrimaryType().getMethods()) {
    if (method.getElementName().equals(name)) {
        //....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's the declaring class you are after, getDeclaringClass() method in IMethodBinding would return the type binding corresponding to the class. From the type binding, you should be able to work your way to the CU through the package fragments if that is what you want.

Comment: I get `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ClassFile` which cannot be casted to `org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit` if the declaring class comes from JAR. However the source for that class is available, so parsing should be possible in theory. Any idea how to achieve that?